# Parse error NuSOAP webservice with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, soap, nusoap

I'm using CodeIgniter with NuSOAP library for webservices and this is the error I get when accessing the Client controller:

```
wsdl error: XML error parsing WSDL from http://localhost/turismoadmin/index.php/Webservice/index/wsdl on line 77: Attribute without value
```

This is the server controller:

```
class Webservice extends CI_Controller {

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('soap_lib');

    $server = new nusoap_server;
    $server->configureWSDL('Agencia Turistica', 'urn:server');
    $server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = 'urn:server';

    $server->register('addcontact',
        array('nombre' => 'xsd:string', 'apellido' => 'xsd:string' , 'ciudad' => 'xsd:string'),
        array('return' => 'xsd:string'));

    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA: '';
    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
}

function index()
{
    if($this->uri->rsegment(3)=="wsdl"){
        $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']="wsdl";
    }else{
        $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']="";
    }

    function addcontact($nombre, $apellido, $ciudad){
        $this->modelo_turismo->addcontact($nombre, $apellido, $ciudad);
        $resultado = $this->modelo_turismo->selectmax_contacto();
        return (json_encode($resultado->fetch_all()));
    }

}
```

}

and this is the Client controller:

```
class Client extends CI_controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function index() {

    $this->load->library('soap_lib');
    $this->nusoap_client = new nusoap_client(site_url('Webservice/index/wsdl'), true);
    $err = $this->nusoap_client->getError();
    if ($err){
        echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    }
    $result1 = $this->nusoap_client->call('addcontact', array("marcos","de lafuente","hermosillo"));
    echo($result1);


    // Check for a fault
    if ($this->nusoap_client->fault) {
        echo '<h2>Fault</h2><pre>';
        print_r($result1);
        echo '</pre>';
    } else {
        // Check for errors
        $err = $this->nusoap_client->getError();
        if ($err) {
            // Display the error
            echo '<h2>Error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
        } else {
            // Display the result
            echo '<h2>Result</h2><pre>';
            print_r($result1);
        echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
}
```

}

I'm trying to do it based
[ON THIS TOPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288523/nusoap-codeigniter-webservice-server-and-client) (Thanks nana.chorage)

I also added this entry to my config/routes.php

```
$route['Webservice/wsdl']="Webservice/index/wsdl";
```

And for not to pass unnoticed, I can see my service when I enter this URL:

```
http://localhost/turismoadmin/index.php/Webservice/wsdl
```

I really dont know what I'm doing wrong, I have searched a lot around and I can't get rid of it!

Answer (score 1):

Then nusoap client URL should be like this

```
$this->nusoap_client = new nusoap_client(site_url('Webservice/index?wsdl'), 'wsdl');
```